# Array from integer: 143 -> [1, 4, 3]

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the shortest way of creating an array consisting of digits from a number?

I don't want to revert to declaring an empty array and then iterating over the number via the `for(a,b,c)` loop.

I would like something more declarative. Ideally, something like:

```
Array.from(143) // => [1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: This is not about code golf, I do not want to sacrifice readability, maintainability and scalability in favor of shortness. On the opposite, I would like to improve readability by getting rid of imperative code that requires brain strain to grasp.

Comment: Then... just define a function `toDigits`. What you do inside the function doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn the number into a string, `split` the string, and turn each character into a number:

```js
const arr = String(143)
  .split('')
  .map(Number);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with the stringed number and [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) as mapping function.

`Array.from` takes an iterable and creates an array. It takes a supplied mapping function and returns a new array with values after using the callback or raw values.

```js
var number = 143,
    array = Array.from(number.toString(), Number);
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string then split then map:

```
const num = 210; 
const numArray = ("" + num).split("").map(Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

As for `Array.from` usage, using map to cast from `string` to `integer`.

Step 1: change `143` to `"143"` by `String(143)`.

Step 2: change `"143"` to `["1", "4", "3"]` by `Array.from("143")`.

Step 3: while pass `Number` function as second parameter in `Array.from`, will change the result of `["1", "4", "3"]` to `[1, 4, 3]` . Which 'Number' will be used as `map function` to iterate every element with it.

Code example:

```js
var intArray = Array.from(String(143), Number);
console.log(intArray);
```

**Update**

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) already has **map function** as its second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to string, [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string then convert each element of the array to Number using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var num = 143;
var splitedNum = num.toString().split('').map(Number);
console.log(splitedNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var n = 143;
var arr = n.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
console.log(arr)
```